# Decrypt aes-256-cbc openssl in C

Tags: ios, c, encryption, commoncrypto

I have a file encrypted using the following openssl command line:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pass pass:somepassword -p -in inputfile.txt -out outputfile.enc
```

The following Java code can decrypt this fine:

```
    byte[] encrypted = getBytesFromInputStream(in);

    String password = "somepassword";

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");

    // Openssl puts SALTED__ then the 8 byte salt at the start of the
    // file. We simply copy it out.
    byte[] salt = new byte[8];
    System.arraycopy(encrypted, 8, salt, 0, 8);
    SecretKeyFactory fact = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL", "BC");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, fact.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 100)));

    // Decrypt the rest of the byte array (after stripping off the salt)
    byte[] data = c.doFinal(encrypted, 16, encrypted.length - 16);
```

It reads the salt and derives the IV from the password as the openssl command line version does.

How would you decrypt this file on iOS using C or ObjC? Would Commoncrypto be a good option, or is it better to stick to the openssl EVP api? I couldn't find any functions for deriving the openssl keyspec in either API, although the API must be there in openssl somewhere as the command line utility is using it.

I'd guess using commoncrypto would be the preferred way? Is there a way to replicate the PBE Key Spec in commoncrypto?

Comment: The issue (for me) is the documentation. Where is the documentation for the OpenSSL derivation of an iv from the password. Where is the documentation for the JAVA Provider "BC"? "PBE Key Spec" is vague, probably this corresponds to PBKDF2 with MD5 in Common Crypto but the parameters are needed, the input, salt and repetition count. It is a common issue that little detailed documentation is provided to allow interoperability in these methods that do many steps rolled into one.

Comment: Agreed. Apparently the spec for the openssl pbe keyspec is 'how openssl does it' ...

Comment: Look for `EVP_BytesToKey` to find the spec for the OpenSSL proprietary key derivation.